# Android Unable to type in edit text in listview in lollipop version

Tags: android, performance, types, android-edittext

I have a listview with custom adapter. In that adapter i have implement another listview and set custom adapter on that listview. In second adapter, i have multiple edit texts. But i am unable to type in Those edit texts in Lollipop version. But same thing runs in Kitkat. Please help me in this problem. Thanks!

Comment: It works fine in kitkat.

Answer (score 0):

user below line for edittext in xml

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

For more detail you can check it [here](https://vikaskanani.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/android-focusable-edittext-inside-listview/)

Comment: I used that but the problem still exist.. It works fine in kitkat.. But the problem exists in lollipop.